# How to run multiple two separate QGraphicsOpacityEffect on two separate QLabels simultaneously

Tags: pyqt5, qlabel

Say you have two QLabels a QWindow, `label1` and `label2`, and you want to run a `QGraphicsOpacityEffect` on both of them. The two effects must start at the same time, play simultaneously, but last differing lengths of time in total.

I have done so many Google searches. Cannot find any explanation, only one on doing two separate animations on the SAME widget - NOT what I am trying to do.

Any help would be greatly appreciated xoxo

I tried using QThread, QThreadPool, and QParallelAnimationGroup, but none of these *seemed* to be able to suffice, but maybe I'm just inexperienced.

Comment: Please provide a [mre] and explain what time difference you're experiencing (or how you're computing it).

Comment: @musicamante while making an MRE I solved my own problem, rather embarrassing but at least it's done. I ended up making an array of animations and adding each one to that rather than redefining a single animation variable. Will write more when I add an answer. Thanks I guess?

Comment: Ok, good for you, but consider that right now your question is not reproducible, and even if your solution is effective, it would hardly be useful to anybody else, since it lacks the context of the problem. Note that in this kind of situations, you either [edit] your question and provide a valid context (including a MRE), or you delete it completely.

Comment: @musicamante I'd say that my question was pretty specific to the context of the problem, no? Two opacity effects on two separate elements simultaneously using the appropriate PyQt5 tools. Hard to misconstrue.

Comment: It was not, because nobody knew how you implemented it. And, in fact, that was your exact problem: without knowing that you recreated the same animation (which has absolutely no mention in your question) how could we help you in a reliable way? The reality is that your problem was not "two opacity effect", but continuously overwriting the same one, and we had absolutely no way to know that. Questions must always be specific, and provide all required details. This is not a forum or help desk, if you ask generic questions, you'll never get acceptable answers.

Comment: My question was not asking about my implementation, I was asking for any solution to the overall task of running two animations simultaneously. I was not asking for someone to look at my failed attempts, I was asking for someone to show me *any* way of doing the animations in PyQt5. That is all the specificity I wanted. I did not expect people to know I was overwriting it because that is only one of the several things I tried, I wanted someone to come up with a novel solution because I had been unable to before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a muppet. Certified Doo-Doo head. Anyway I figured it out.

Basically, instead of redefining a single `self.animation` value each time I launch a new animation (which stops the old one, silly goose), I have an array of animations that I had new ones to. Here's the MRE I made to do it:

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QPropertyAnimation, QAbstractAnimation
import sys


class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowTitle('Window')
        self.animations = []

        self.label1 = QLabel('Label 1!', self)
        self.label1.move(10, 10)
        self.label2 = QLabel('Label 2!', self)
        self.label2.move(10, 110)

        self.showMaximized()
        self.fadeOutSequence()

    def animateWidget(self, widget, duration):
        effect = QGraphicsOpacityEffect()
        self.animations.append(QPropertyAnimation(effect, b'opacity'))
        widget.setGraphicsEffect(effect)
        self.animations[len(self.animations)-1].setDuration(duration)
        self.animations[len(self.animations)-1].setStartValue(0)
        self.animations[len(self.animations)-1].setEndValue(1)
        self.animations[len(self.animations)-1].start(QAbstractAnimation.DeleteWhenStopped)

    def fadeOutSequence(self):
        self.animateWidget(self.label1, 4000)
        self.animateWidget(self.label2, 8000)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```